# How to update SQL data only if 1 hour is passed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with a coupon code website, it has a products section. Instead of pulling data from API server of shopping sites every time a visitor loads the page, I want to store the data in SQL and use it..
But the data should update every hour or only if an hour is passed.
cron job is not required as I dont want to happen it automatically.
If there is 100 webpage users in an hour, they will get the same data, but when the first user comes after 1 hour time, it should overwrite the products's information in SQL.

I got the following code from w3schools.com and it work fine for saving data in SQL.
I hope some can help me to overwrite data only if it the data older than 1 hour. Otherwise it should act as  "data already exists".

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "nuser";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

$ProductId = "smartphone";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$check=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from testdb where productid='$ProductId'");
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

   if($checkrows>0) {
      echo "Data Already Exists";
   } else {  
    //insert results from the form input


$sql = "INSERT INTO Flipkart (productid, title, price)
VALUES ('productid','title','price')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();}
?>
```

The above code saves data in database, it can also detect duplicate data. but I want to add just one more function, which will overwrite data if the current data time is older than 1 hour. database has a TIMESTAMP "reg_date" column, which stores created date and time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

I am new to SQL and php, so pardon me if there is any problems with the question...

Comment: Use a cron job which should must run after every one hour

Comment: You need to store the timestamp of when you last updated the data somewhere, and then you simply check if more than one hour has passed between that and now. If not, you fetch your cached data from the database, otherwise you make your API call to get current data, and write it to your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron job.

This is the best explanation with code for PHP I have found so far for cron job:
     https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428